# MongoDB Aggregate Match very slow following Project

Tags: mongodb

I have an aggregate query within MongoDB that contains 5 stages in the pipeline. A match, lookup, project, project and match.  If the final match yields no results, the query takes 45 seconds.  If the match yields results then it takes less than 100ms.

```
db.instances.aggregate([ 
{ $match: { "Record.Closed": null } }, 
{ $lookup: { from: "messages", localField: "Record.ApprovalId", foreignField: "Record.ApprovalId", as: "approvalMessages" } }, 
{ $project: { Record: 1, parsed: 
       { $filter: { input: "$approvalMessages", as: "item", cond: { $or: [ { $eq: [ "$Record.LastRoundupSent", null ] }, 
       { $gte: [ "$$item.Record.Created", "$Record.LastRoundupSent" ] } ] } } } } },
 { $project: { Record: 1, MessageCount: { $size: "$parsed" } } } , 
 { $match: { "MessageCount" : { $gt : 0 } } } 
 ])
```

The final `$match` causes my query to hang when it returns 0 results.
If I change this to: `{ $match: { "MessageCount" : { $eq : 0 }}}` then its fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I guess parsed is returning an Array which is being projected to Message count as size. but in final match you are direclty checking MessageCount which is Object and not Array so you should try  MessageCount.size

Comment: how many documents do you have in this collection? What are the indexes you have on those two collctions?